# Expose the Restful API to mobile app and other 3rd Party companies

Tags: asp.net, rest

We have help desk  web application developed in asp.net. Now we have requirement to expose Restful API to our mobile app and to 3rd party companies.We do not want to expose all the API methods to 3rd party companies.They would be using some methods of the API.

Currently i am thinking to expose Restful API within the help desk application.
Our web application is hosted in support.domain.com and want to expose our API within this URL example api.support.domain.com

My question 
how  to design Restful API with private method which will be only used by our mobile app and not expose to other and public APIs method to 3rd party companies?.

Answer (score 1):

If you are OK with having 2 different APIs, then you can create one and only expose it privately, and create the second one and expose it publicly.

If you only want to have a single API, then you'll need to implement authorization. Basically on each method call that is protected, check to see if the caller is allowed to invoke the method, if they aren't, throw an exception or return a response indicating they are not allowed to perform the requested action.

How you authenticate a caller is up to you. You can go with a username/password scheme, or generate some sort of string that will work as an API key that that will be used for every call.

If it's an option, you can also do it based on IP address -- if you know internal calls must come from a specific set of subnets, then check the IP address. You can also keep a table of external IP addresses that are allowed.

Comment: thank Brain for your reply but having 2 different APIs method means hosting it separately and maintaining it future will have problems.